# Configuring Eclipse for Drools

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools

I'm new to drools and I'm trying to configure drools in Eclipse IDE. I manged to install the drools plugin, but I'm stuck at installing GEF plugin. I'm using this link to install the plugin http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/ and see many options. Options doesn't match with the options in the drools documentation. Please check the screen shot below. Also if someone can point out whats the use of this plugin and how we can actually use this it will be really helpful.

[image]

Comment: Did you able to manage which plugin from this massive list of options that will do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, installing Drools messed up some of Spring STS plugin features in my eclipse. I used JBOSS Developer Studio and had no problems (ships with all Drools related tools), I downloaded it from [jboss-downloads](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/).